# How to filter String text cell?

Tags: excel, excel-2007, excel-formula, excel-2003

I want to use SUMPROCUT function on condition that the sheet's row count is unknown.
so the formula was writen by *=SUMPRODUCT(--F:F,--G:G)*, after Enter key be pressed *#VALUE!* showed up.
I realized that columns name are string type but they were included in calculation, that could be the problem. 
how to avoid String text in SUMPRODUCT function? or maybe you have a smarter way, please help.
thanks in advanced!

[UPDATED - screentshot & orginal requirements]
clients asked me a formula to calculate sum(column F * column G), such as 10*470 + 5*350 + 5*5.5 + 25*180 + 4*48 + 6*15 + 80*4.5 + 70*5.44, and I don't know how many rows in their sheet caused they want a general formula to deal with all excel file

[image]

Comment: you could show us what your data look like (with a screenshot or an example) so that we could help you solve the *root* issue and avoid an [XY Problem](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=542341)

Comment: Do you really need the double negatives `--`? Without these `SUMPRODUCT` will ignore rows containing text.

Comment: @JMax you right, it perhaps XY problem I've updated question.

Comment: @rock: you were definetly right to edit your question :). I'll have a try

Comment: @lori_m -- I know what's your meaning, -- will handle the situation that client indicates the column wrong type such as String, it will arised a exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a try:

```
=SUMPRODUCT($F2:INDEX($F:$F,MATCH(9.9999E+307,$F:$F)), $G2:INDEX($G:$G,MATCH(9.9999E+307,$G:$G)))
```

Provided that your values end on the same row.

Some explanation:

- `index()` can return a reference as well as a value (we are using it as a reference here)
- the 9.9999E+307 is a *trick* - basically, if you look for a number larger than any number in a range of numbers (& 9.9999E+307 is about the largest number excel can cope with, so works in most cases), `match()` will return the position of the last number on the list, which is what we want

Inspiration found [here](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/showthread.php?270775-sum-a-range-of-unknown-size) but I found this trick very clever and smart :)

Comment: bravo, it's incredible...that's work really fine, thanks @JMax, I have to dig it into to learn those two formulas.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `=SUMPRODUCT(F:F,G:G)`  (that is, without the `--`)

Comment: Which duplicates my comment... I interpreted the response as meaning that the `--` might be needed in case a number is entered as text but normally you can just convert any non-numeric numbers using the tooltip option.

Comment: @lori_m I have to say you are absolutely right, sorry for delay appreciation